# Maximum number of function overloads?

Tags: c++, function

In C++ is there a maximum number of functions that can overload each other?

I'm getting perplexing "no matching function" errors. I have an overloaded `encode` function with about 900 different versions for each struct/value type that I'm encoding (including templates for arrays/vectors). The encode functions call each other depending on which fields need to be encoded.

If I put my `encode(std::string)` function at the bottom of the files (.h & .cpp) the calls to it return "no matching function". If it's near the top then they don't.

**What's going on and, more importantly, how should I fix it?**

(linux gcc version 4.6.1)

Comment: you have 900 overloads?????? ?? ????? I would start by grouping the overloads appropriately, normally most compilers support a version option... read your compiler's manual..

Comment: Why do you consider 900 overloads is a lot? What about overloads of `stream operator << (stream, smtn_other)` ?

Comment: @Nim Well, it's a plugin which I'm compiling with `make install` for the main program. This links in all the libraries from the main program so I can refer to them in my encoding plugin. I think it's using gcc, which would be version 4.6.1

Comment: @Lol4t0: I'm not sure about how many overloads there is for `operator<<()` but I would fail to name more than 50.

Comment: This squarely fits Raymond Chen's line "If you have to ask, you're probably doing something wrong".  I'll put a buck on actually having 1025 overloads.

Comment: When you move one from the bottom to the top, does the new bottom stop functioning?

Comment: @Hans: g++ version 4.5.2 under MinGW can handle 2500 overloads. (I know because I just tried it out.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By your description of the error appearing and disappearing based on where you put the function, this has nothing to do with the number of overloads.  Rather, the problem is that you're trying to call an overload before its declared.

When you have a bunch of functions that all call each other like you describe (regardless of whether they are overloads or have distinct names), you generally need to first DECLARE all the functions and then DEFINE them later after all the definitions have been seen.  Usually you structure this so the declarations are all in a header file (so other files and include it) and the definitions are all in a source file (which includes the header), so this all works easily.  Things get more complex if you have inline functions (which generally need to be defined in the header file to be inlined in all compilation units), but the overall pattern is the same -- first DECLARE everything, and then DEFINE everything.

**edit**

where exactly are you getting the 'no matching overload' error? -- you need to move the DEFINITION containing the call that is getting that error AFTER the DECLARATION of the encode function (or move the encode DECLARATION before the DEFINITION with the error).  As long as ALL DECLARATIONS are before ALL DEFINITIONS, the ordering will be ok.

Comment: I have put all my function declarations and templates in a header and function definitions in a source file so I don't think this applies to my case. When I said "function at the bottom of the files" I was referring to moving the declaration to the bottom of the header and the definition to the bottom of the source.

Comment: You were right! I somehow was thinking about templates not needing a separate definition because they're in the header file. I gave all my templates definitions at the top of the header and moved their definitions to the bottom and everything works! :)